# Sincronizar ProgressBar com Execução de métodos de uma classe

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos, delegate

No meu projeto tenho uma classe que possui três métodos:

```
static List<string> ListaArquivos(string path){...}
static void CriaArquivoUnico(List<string> listaArquivos){...}
static void AbreArquivoUnico(string pathArquivoUnico){...}
```

O que estou tentando fazer é com que sempre que ele entrar em um método ele gere um evento dizendo que entrou naquele método, com isso vou atualizar um campo com o status da tarefa, ou seja, quando entrar no ListaArquivos eu atualizo o textbox para "Listando Arquivos", por exemplo. E quando sair do método eu preciso de outro evento avisando que ele saiu do método. Como posso criar esses eventos ?

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples de fazer isso seria através da utilização do `BackgroundWorker`

Com base no seu exemple montei um cenário onde serão lidos os nomes dos arquivos de um diretório, adicionando cada um desses arquivos numa lista, e para cada arquivo lido será atualizado num TextBox a porcentagem de arquivos lidos, podendo ser atualizado um `ProgressBar` no lugar do `TextBox`.

```
    List<string> ListaArquivos(string path)
    {
        List<string> listArquivos = new List<string>();

        BackgroundWorker workerLeituraArquivos = new BackgroundWorker();
        workerLeituraArquivos.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        workerLeituraArquivos.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var arrayArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayArquivos.Length; i++)
            {
                listArquivos.Add(arrayArquivos[i]);

                // calculo da porcentagem concluida
                var porcentagem = (100 / arrayArquivos.Length) * (i + 1);
                workerLeituraArquivos.ReportProgress(porcentagem);

                // adicionado apenas para dar tempo de notar a alteração do textbox
                Thread.Sleep(1000); 
            }
        };

        workerLeituraArquivos.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            txtStatus.Text = string.Format("Listando arquivos. {0}% concluído", e.ProgressPercentage);
        };

        workerLeituraArquivos.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "Listagem de arquivos concluída";
        };

        workerLeituraArquivos.RunWorkerAsync();

        return listArquivos;
    }
```

Uma outra forma a ser feita seria criar uma classe que estendesse `EventArgs`e criar um `EventHandler`, mas ai teria que ser feito outros tratamentos para conseguir atualizar a UI.